# How do I use both keyboard return keys in python code, I can bind the main, but not the numeric return

Tags: python, keyboard-events, pysimplegui

```
...

    PSG.theme('Dark Blue 3')
    PSG.set_options(font='Arial, 14')
    layout = [
        [PSG.Text("What book ISBN would you like to find?"), PSG.In(key='bisbn')],
        [PSG.Text("What book Title woukd you like to find?"), PSG.In(key='btitle')],
        [PSG.Button('Done', visible=True, bind_return_key=True)]
    ]
    gwindow = PSG.Window('Book ISBN', layout).Finalize()
    gwindow.move(x=450, y=300)
    event, values = gwindow.read()
    bookisbn = values['bisbn']
    booktitle = values['btitle']
    gwindow.close()

...
```

As you can see, I can bind the main return key but have not found anything to bind the numeric return key.

Answer (score 2):

The the numeric `return` work for the default binding `'<Return>'` on my WIN10, maybe not for other platforms.

Maybe you can try to bind those Input elements with the event `'<KP_Enter>'` after window finalized.

Demo code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Input(expand_x=True, key='IN 1')],
    [sg.Input(expand_x=True, key='IN 2')],
    [sg.Text("", expand_x=True, justification='center', key='-TEXT-'),
     sg.Button("Button", bind_return_key=True)],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

for key in ('IN 1', 'IN 2'):
    window[key].widget.bind('<KP_Enter>', window[key]._ReturnKeyHandler)

index = 0
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Button":
        index += 1
        window['-TEXT-'].update(f"Enter {index} times")

window.close()
```